# How do I delete a node from a binary search tree

Tags: c++

How do I implement a function to delete a node from a binary search tree? Below is my current function:

```
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&tree) {
    TreeNode *NodeToDelete;
    NodeToDelete = tree;
    TreeNode *InOrder;

    if (tree->right == NULL && tree->left == NULL) {
        delete NodeToDelete;
    }
    if (tree->right == NULL) {
        tree = tree->left;
        delete NodeToDelete;
    }
    else if (tree->left == NULL) {
        tree = tree->right;
        delete NodeToDelete;
    }
    else {
        InOrder = tree->right;
        while (InOrder->left != NULL) {
            InOrder = InOrder->left; 
        }

        NodeToDelete->value = InOrder->value;
        remove(InOrder, InOrder->value);
    }
}
```

And here is the `remove` function I have that locates the value to be deleted:

```
    void remove(TreeNode *&tree, ANY num) {//Removed Need for ">"
    if (tree == NULL){
        return;
    }

    if (tree->value == num) {
        makeDeletion(tree);
    } else if (num < tree->value) {
        remove(tree->left, num);
    } else {
        remove(tree->right, num);
    }
};//Remove
```

As it stands I feel like I'm very close, but when I go to output the contents of the binary tree the program crashes. I am trying to use an approach where, if the node has two children, I locate the in order successor, swap the values of the nodes of the in order successor and the node to be "deleted," and then delete the in order successor. Without adjusting the `remove` function, what bit of information am I missing to make the `makeDeletion` function work as described?

EDIT: in the `makeDeletion` function I mistakenly wrote two `if` statements in succession. The second `if` statement should be an `else if` statement.

Comment: Can you provide full source code and some input data?

Comment: I'm fairly new to using stack overflow, so is there a way to post files without writing posting the whole code? I have two files where one defines the binary tree and one tests it.

Comment: You may put your code and data somewhere else and provide the link here

Comment: @abdullah No, code needs to be posted within the question, not offsite.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm sorry, I did not know that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `makeDeletion`, if `tree` is a leaf (both `left` and `right` are `NULL`), you delete the leaf node, and don't set `tree = nullptr`.  This leaves a dangling reference in your tree to memory that has been freed.  Also, you then dereference the (now deleted) node in the next `if`.  Either one of these can result in your crash.

Comment: I apologize, that next `if` was supposed to be an `else if`. That being said, would `tree = NULL` work as well as `tree = nullptr`?

Comment: Yes.  `NULL` and `nullptr` can both be used.

Comment: By the way, making `tree = nullptr` fixed my issue. Thank you!